# Join two collections and apply a condition in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections:

1. student_classes

```
[
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('60923c997b4d3205009a981a'),
        'studentId': ObjectId('608a42e8224c549ad9a9ab51'),
        'classId': ObjectId('60312a59c824a213c1d014af'),
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('609392ad31db141f56afb043'),
        'studentId': ObjectId('608a42e8224c549ad9a9ab51'),
        'classId': ObjectId('60914922749cd2f796f01efe'),
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('609392ad31db141f56afb044'),
        'studentId': ObjectId('608a42e8224c549ad9a9ab51'),
        'classId': ObjectId('6091468e749cd2f796f01efd'),
    },
];
```

And classes collection:

```
[
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('60312a59c824a213c1d014af'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-03-18T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('6091468e749cd2f796f01efd'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-05-18T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('60914922749cd2f796f01efe'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-03-18T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('6091494a749cd2f796f01eff'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-05-20T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('60914953749cd2f796f01f00'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-05-22T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('60914957749cd2f796f01f01'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-05-24T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('6091495c749cd2f796f01f02'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-05-26T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('60914972749cd2f796f01f03'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-05-26T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('60914981749cd2f796f01f04'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-05-28T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('60914989749cd2f796f01f05'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-05-30T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
    {
        '_id': ObjectId('6091499f749cd2f796f01f06'),
        'name': 'Holistic Yoga For Beginners - Class',
        'classDateTime': '2021-05-19T07:10:00.628Z',
    },
];
```

I want to select all the entries classes for a student (from student_classes) where the classDateTime is greater than a particular date. The two collections are linked by student_classes.classId and classes._id.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
{
    $lookup:
        {
            from: 'classes',
            let: { classId: '$classId' },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and:
                                [
                                    { $eq: ['$_id', '$$classId'] },
                                    { $gt: ['$classDateTime', '2021-05-05T06:35:05.226+00:00'] },
                                ],
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            as: 'classInfo',
        },
};
```

But this does not work. I still get all the records from student_classes collection. What's the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to put match condition after your lookup stage to filter classes that does not have empty result,

```
  { $lookup: { .. } },
  { $match: { classInfo: { $ne: [] } } }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WZ1wtpF9wNE)

Answer (score 1):

While you've got your answer that you just need to match sure the `classInfo` field is not empty after the look like in the following pipeline:

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HZGgDygBBt0)

I want to suggest you start your query from the `class` collection, currently you are querying the entire student collection and `$lookup`ing on all of it. this is very very inefficient. especially as the `student` collection scale will increase.

By starting the query from the `classes` collection you can index the `classDateTime` and initially fetch a much smaller dataset for your pipeline, here's how I would do it:

```
db.classes.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      classDateTime: {
        $gt: "2021-05-05T06:35:05.226+00:00"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "students",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "classId",
      as: "studentsInfo"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$studentsInfo"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$studentsInfo",
          {
            name: "$name",
            classDateTime: "$classDateTime"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/42lPcBt7Ra-)

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks a ton for your suggestion. In my case, my API gets StudentId as input. I need to get all the classes for that StudentId. That's the reason I start from student_classes collection. Hope that's the right approach.

Comment: If you're querying a single student then yea, it's the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join collections first and then do the rest of the magic. Try this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Also small notice regarding database model design, I suggest you just embed the documents with help of arrays. Thus you could avoid doing joins.

Comment: I did try this too:
{"$lookup":{
    "from":"classes",
    "localField":"classId",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"classInfo"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$classInfo"},
  {"$match":{"classInfo.classDateTime":{$gte: new Date()}}}

Comment: I wonder whether you have records that match your request? Try without the `$match` stage and see what you have.